# Servlet that have 2 resultset loop

Tags: java, mysql, sql, servlets, while-loop

in my servlet, i had join two table and want to display one table once and another table as long as there is data not displayed. This servlet will displayed its attribute based on the chosen id,

heres the code

```
 Connection con;
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kps","root","KPSAdmin1234!");
        ps = con.prepareStatement("Select * from applicant a INNER JOIN JOB B where A.J_ID = B.J_ID AND B.J_ID = '" + j_id + "'" );
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next())
        {
            //1st table

            String j_title = rs.getString("j_title");
            String j_description = rs.getString("j_description");
            String j_location = rs.getString("j_location");
            String j_type = rs.getString("j_type");
            String j_empType = rs.getString("j_empType");
            String d_name = rs.getString("d_name");
            String j_responsibilities = rs.getString("j_responsibilities");
            String j_salary = rs.getString("j_salary");

            //2nd table
            String js_id = rs.getString("js_id");
            String js_name = rs.getString("js_name");
            String js_ic = rs.getString("js_ic");
            String js_mobile = rs.getString("js_mobile");
            String js_email = rs.getString("js_email");

            //<!-- want to display once -->
            pw.println("<div class=\"panel-body\">");
            pw.println("<title>"+j_title+"</title>");

            pw.println("<div class=\"column left\">");
            pw.println("<div style=\"font-family: Barlow;\">");
            pw.println("<font size = \"5\";>"  + j_title+"</font>");
            pw.println("<h5><font size = \"2\";>&nbsp;<img src=\"img/location.png\"style=\"width:12px;height:12px;\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + j_location + "</td>");

            pw.println("<br><br><strong><p>RESPONSIBILITIES</p></strong>");
            pw.println("<br><p>" +  j_responsibilities + "</p><br></td>");
            pw.println("<br><br><strong><p>REQUIREMENT</p></strong>");
            pw.println("<br><p>" +  j_description + "</p></td>");
            pw.println("</div>");
            pw.println("</div>");

            pw.println("<div class=\"column right\">");

            pw.println("<br>&nbsp;<img src=\"img/rm.png\"style=\"width:16px;height:16px;\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"  + j_salary );
            pw.println("<br>&nbsp;<img src=\"img/check.png\"style=\"width:14px;height:14px;\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"  + j_type );
            pw.println("<br>&nbsp;<img src=\"img/briefcase.png\"style=\"width:14px;height:14px;\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + j_empType + "<br><br>");

            pw.println("</div>");
            pw.println("</div>");
            pw.println("</div>");
            pw.println("</div>");
            //<!--end of display once-->

            //want to display as long as there is data in the database so basically while(rs.next()) 
            pw.println("<div class=\"row\">");
            pw.println("<div class=\"col-lg-12\">");
            pw.println("<section class=\"panel\">");
            pw.println("<header class=\"panel-heading\">List Of Applicant</header>");
            pw.println("<div class=\"panel-body\">");
            pw.println("<br><font size = \"3\"<br><a href='resume.jsp?js_id=" + js_id +"'>" +js_name+ "</a></font>");
            pw.print(" <font size=\"2\" "+ js_ic +"&ensp;|&ensp;" +js_email +"&ensp;|&ensp;"+ js_mobile);

            pw.println("&ensp;&ensp;<a class=\"btn btn-primary\" href='ViewJobApplicant?js_id=" + js_id +"'>View Response</a></font>");

        }
```

how can i be able to do that?
[the viewservlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Uc7M.jpg)

i have tried putting the 1st table outside while but all i got is this error

```
 java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
```

yeah, so it have to be in the while
so i made two while with different sql query each and the error said it cant run another while when a while has stop..

is there any solution?

Comment: I suggest you adopt a MVC paradigm.  Servlet is for getting the data and JSP is for displaying the data

Comment: @ScaryWombat so i need to convert the servlet into jsp?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL you show will return many rows for the first table `applicant`, with accompannying rows of the second one `job`. Well... you have two issues in your code:

- You need to `ORDER BY` the rows by the first table rows. Probably you want to use a key, ideally the primary key of the table. Something like `order by applicant.id`.
- Second, you need to "detect" when you are changing from one `applicant` to the next one. You need to add logic whiel retrieving the rows that detect the applicant change and display it accordingly.